# Working in two different git branches at the same time in Databricks

Tags: git, databricks, databricks-repos

Is there a possibility to work in two different branches at once on Databricks?

If I open one branch in tab window (1) and then open another branch in another tab(2), the first tab window(1) automatically changes the git branch to the other tab(2). I think this is really nice if you forget to change your branch in one tab window, but if you want to work on two different projects, this can be annoying.

Hopefully, someone has already found a workaround for this.

Comment: I'm not sure about Databricks, [but you can with git using worktrees](https://devtut.github.io/git/worktrees.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create two different checkouts for the same repository inside your folder - when you click "Add Repo" you can give another name for directory in the "Repo name" field, for example, `project-branch1` or something like...